# Можно ли обойтись в дочерних таблицах без своего id?

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Будет ли считаться правильным, если у дочерних таблиц будет такой же id, как и у родительской? (Внешние ключи будут совпадать)

На примере ниже общие данные таблиц "Преподаватели" и "Студенты" вынесены в таблицу "Пользователи". При этом я хочу убрать внешние ключи "Пользователь" в этих таблицах, напрямую взяв id пользователь из таблицы "Пользователи".

Можно ли назвать это правильным вариантом?

[image: Структура БД]

Comment: По моему мнению скорее нет чем да, во первых потребуются лишние проверки  к какой таблице  относятся пользователи (студент или нет) во вторых без  уникального id таблица users плохо проиндексируеться, хотя тут все зависит от того как и какие запросы вы будете делать к бд

Comment: Можно, чё... уникальность ИД студентов и лекторов схема обеспечивает, а для PK запрета референситься на другой уник вроде как нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ничего неправильного в этом нет. Классический пример наследования таблиц. Только для правильного дизайна поле `id` в таблицах `студенты` и `преподаватели` должно быть одновременно и первичным ключом в этих таблицах и внешним ключом, который ссылается на поле `id` (которое тоже является первичным ключом) из `users`